# tomcat soapui mock web services

Tags: web-services, tomcat, soapui

I have a .war file which was created from a soapui mock service via the 'deployaswar' option and deployed to Tomcat 5.5. I can successfully view the WSDL in firefox but noticed the the schemaLocation attribute for my xsd import is invalid. Here is the current URL format:

http://localhost:8080/?WSDL&interface=UserServicePortBinding&part=User.xsd

It's missing the web application name in tomcat. I verified this by constructing the correct URL and viewing the xsd:

http://localhost:8080/wartest?WSDL&interface=UserServicePortBinding&part=User.xsd

I also noticed the other references in the xsd have the same issue. How can I correct this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out for myself. It was a matter of using "Deploy directory or WAR file located on server" to deploy the war and setting the context path to: /

That allowed everything to work correctly.